# Setting a Callback for an HttpResponse

Tags: asp.net

I'm consuming a 3rd party API (REST JSON-based).  In it they require a callback url so I can grab a token that's returned.

So how does this work?  If I give them a url, how is it hooking back up to my callback method?  How do I specify the method or where it's at once the response gets back... how do you wire all this?

So in the header of my `HttpRequest`, I'm adding a custom value of "callbackUrl", "ourCallbackUrlHere" as required by the API.

Comment: Do you mean they require you to specify a URL on your server that they will call back to in order to verify some data? So not so much you 'grabbing' it, but them 'pushing' it?

Comment: in order to send some data back yes...to send a token string to us.  I think they'll be sending a token back via our callback url so http://callbackurl/someToken=234#@Gas643g as I need to grab that value somehow when sent back to our callback url..which is how I'm not sure that works..how do I grab it ?  If I get a response back, then ok how is this callback url being used?

Comment: check out http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849 and search on "callback URI provided by the client
   in the previous request".  So the host will send me back http://ourcallbackUrl?oauth_token=hh5s93j4hdidpola&oauth_verifier=hfdp7dh39dks9884 as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the term 'callback' might be causing some confusion here. They are speaking of a 'callback URL' in the sense that they are calling back to a URL on your server. They don't mean that your server's initial request code should have any sort of 'callback' implemented to handle it, however.

What you will do is implement a handler - perhaps an `ASHX` generic handler - that pulls the `QueryString` values their server sends, and verifies it against what you have in your database, taking appropriate action.

So, there will be two pages/handlers: the one that *sends* the initial API request via REST, and the one that receives the 'callback' that the third-party issues. But you *aren't* implementing a callback (as in, a .NET `delegate`) in your first handler.

Comment: Ok so how do you sync the first handler with the second bringing back the token?

Comment: I don't think I need 2 though.  My server-side code in a wrapper project that wraps this third party API so that we can use it that I'm building is sending out the initial request.  I think I'll just need a handler to receive the callback (token via our url we specify to them).

Comment: You wouldn't sync them. Put off what ever actions you would be taking on the first handler; don't take "official" action at all until you get the token back from the third party. Is this being done on a user-facing website? So a user does something that triggers the API call? If so, you should implement some sort of page that says, "We're processing..." and perhaps auto-refreshes to a status URL that checks to see if the token has come back, yet. That means you need to store state somewhere (*not* in session, because the callback will be in a different session)

Comment: but what if you don't have a UI yet....and you are creating a wrapper around that 3rd party REST api.  Then I want to unit test this stuff (test whether the temp credentials, auth, and access token was received) along with using the final access token...I don't have a UI to work with I just want to consume my wrapper and make calls to this API using full OAuth dance...so how is that done then?

Comment: It's actually integration testing (not unit testing), and the company should provide a test interface you can hit, then make sure you test callback uri responds properly.

Comment: that's what I'm saying...sorry bear with me.  Yea they have a test console but it's being phased out.  See I need to be able to test real objects in my wrapper, not just use a console.  So that is where I get stuck with implementing the full OAuth...cause where you redirect to that /authorize endpoint, you have to interact with it manually through a UI?  We are just going to be using this wrapper of mine to make calls to create reports on stuff...not really gonna want a UI to log into, we just want to hit my wrapper straight up, get the auth, start making API calls.